# jQuery: why does my live() handler declaration error out when the analogous click() one doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in a javascript file (using jQuery as well):

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').live('click',myObject.someMethod);
});

var myObject = { 
    someMethod: function() { //do stuff }
};
```

I get a js error on pageload that says "myObject isn't defined". However, when I change the event handler in the `doc.ready` function to:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(){ myObject.someMethod(); });
```

it works! I have code structured like the first example all over my codebase that works. W T F??

Comment: thank you @allenjb and @spender, but neither of you are correct. `document.ready` fires AFTER the DOM is initialized, meaning that `myObject` has already been defined, as it is a global object. Hence, WTF. I'm running this code in FF 3.6.3

Comment: But if the DOM is already initialized, jQuery.ready() fires immediately and synchronously.

Comment: jquery.ready fires only after the DOM is initialized, which takes place after everything is loaded. that means ALL files, including the JS file calling the jquery.ready, meaning that the object (global obj declared outside of jquery.ready) MUST BE DEFINED before jquery.ready fires. do you see the dilemma?

Comment: here's another wrinkle. the top code block works on a fellow dev's machine. also, this works in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66hnS/ GAHHHH

Comment: Try console.logging myObject at various places.

Answer (score 5):

In the first code block, you're trying to assign the value of myObject.someMethod (which is declared after this code block) to the second parameter for live().

When you wrap it in an anonymous function, as in the second block, the anonymous function doesn't get executed until the live event gets triggered. myObject.someMethod has been created by this point, so the code works as expected.

Comment: also, it shouldn't matter whatever i'm declaring in the first block first because the first block doesn't run until page load, whereas the object declaration runs immediately upon script load....

Comment: What if the page is already loaded? From the docs: "If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately." Looks like this might be the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the lookup on `myObject` is deferred until the point at which the click handler is executed. In the first case, (in some cases, see below) the lookup must be immediate... as `myObject` is not yet defined, you get an error. Is there any reason not to add the event handler after `myObject` has been declared and assigned?

EDIT

As commented above, is it possible that this code is running after the `.ready()` event has fired.

jQuery docs say this about the `.ready()` method:

> If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.

In this case, your ready handler will fire synchronously, thus requiring `myObject` to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the document.ready scope has another variable named myObject which hides the original one?

Comment: well... myObject isn't really the name. i generalized the code. this would be a good guess but a search of my code shows that there are no variables with that name (the actual name is "Conversions", which is a brand new object introduced today, and this is the first js I've written for it :\ ). thanks tho!